# блоки сообщений как в вк

Tags: html, jquery, css

я сделал такую вот небольшую ленту с двумя пользователями:
html

```
<div class="msg_block">
            <div class="users_msg_block">
                <a data-triger="user1" class="new_msg_user"><img src="/images/icons/users/consultation_filled-32.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
                <a data-triger="user2" class="new_msg_user"><img src="/images/icons/users/consultation_filled-32.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="msg_bnt_active">
                <a><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
.msg_block {

background-color: #ffab3b;
position: fixed;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
z-index: 9999999;
width: 50px;
border-radius: 30px;

}

.users_msg_block {

    display: inline-grid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.new_msg_user {

    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fe980f;
    border: 1px solid #ffab3b;
    padding: 9px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

}

.msg_bnt_active {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fe980f;
    border: 1px solid #ffab3b;
}

.msg_bnt_active a {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

теперь вопрос в том как сделать чтоб при клике на юзера открывался блок диалога с этим юзером, а при нажатии на msg_bnt_active показывался и скрывался список этих пользователей

блок который будет открываться и закрываться вот:

```
<div class="msg_box">
            <div class="msg_box_header">
                <div><h5>User 1</h5></div>
                <div><a><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="msg_box_wrapper">
            dialog...
            </div>
            <div class="msg_box_footer">
            <input type="text" name="send_message" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

для каждого пользователя должен открываться свой блок с диалогом

Comment: Что будет отображаться какие данные, и где их взять?

Comment: при клике на юзера должен открывался блок диалога с этим юзером. диалог берется из базы, как взять данные я знаю, у меня вопрос конкретно как реализовать открыбите таких диалоговых блоков при нажатии на юзеров (как в вк!)

Answer (score 0):

Ну прям точь в точь я ни делал но похоже

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.top__panel {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ccc;
}

span.trigger {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.top__panel p a {
  color: red;
}

.user {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.user div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.message {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.message i {
  color: lightblue;
}

.message textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20vh;
}

.message div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="panel">
  <div class="top__panel">
    <span>Новое сообщение</span>
    <a href="#">Перейти к диалогу с USER</a>
    <span class="trigger">x</span>
  </div>

  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" style="border-radius:50%;">
    <div>
      <p>Имя Фамилия</p>
      <p>онлайн <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="message">
    <form action="">
      <textarea name=""></textarea>
      <div>
        <p>
          <a href=""><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> </a>
          <a href=""><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> </a>
          <a href=""><i class="fa fa-music"></i> </a>
        </p>
        <button class="btn">Отправить</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```